# Which charts to choose to turn these $\mathbb{R}^2$ an $1-$manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I am thinking about see $\mathbb{R}^2$ as one $1-$manifold.

Trying to this I made some considerations.

If I take $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the following topology:

$$(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau) = \text{the product of $\mathbb{R}$ with the the topologies usual and discrete}$$

Precisely:

$$(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau)  = (\mathbb{R},\tau_{\text{usual}}) \times (\mathbb{R}, \tau_{discrete})$$

Of course this is a topology. So I was wondering, how to find a differentiable structure on this space such that $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau)$ is an one manifold?

The problem I am in front is that is hard to find an bijection between this space and $\mathbb{R}$. How to do this? How to choose this in a continuous way?

Thanks!

Comment: and which function do you suggest to choose in this case?

Comment: Have you checked if your space is disconnected after removing a point? If not it's hopeless.

Comment: I guess my space is totally disconnected, @MaikPickl

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi Unless I'm missing something, it's *not* totally disconnected - it's basically the disjoint union of continuum-many copies of $\mathbb{R}$. So it has large connected components, but too many of them to be a manifold.

Comment: you are right @Noah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is *not* a $1$-manifold, since it is not separable - it has no countable dense subset. (Actually, differentiable manifolds are required to be second-countable, which is a significantly stronger requirement than separability.)

Comment: you are right. Then there cannot exist any homeomorphism between this and $\mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi Yes, it is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. However, neither is the circle, which *is* a one-manifold, so that's not really relevant. A $1$-manifold just has to be *locally homeomorphic* to $\mathbb{R}$, which this is (the connected components each are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: yes, you are right, but how about locally homeomorphic? How can I show that this can have neighborhoods homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi Given a point $(a, b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, what can you say about the set $X_a=\{(a, x): x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ in the topology you describe? HINT: Think about what the discrete topology, and the product topology, mean . . .

Comment: it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: thank you! I already know what to do. I will define the following homeomorphisms: $\phi_a : \mathbb{R} \to X_a$, $\phi_a(x) = (a,x).$ It is injective and bijective. An obvious inverse to this map is the projection onto the second component. That is a continuous and open map, then $\phi_a$ is an homeomorphism. obviously $\{X_a\}$ convers $\mathbb{R}^2$ and neither of these sets overlap.